# Guardar resultados a dos pestañas de excel

Tags: r

Parto de dos df:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = '
         id     col2  col3     col4
         1       N      H        A
         2       N     H        B
         3       S      M        C
         4       S      M        C
         5       S      M        D
         6       N      M        E
         7       S     M        B', header = TRUE)




df2 <- read.table(text = '
         id     col2  col3     col4
         1       N      H        A
         2       N     H        B
         3       S      M        A
         4       N      M        A
         5       S      M        D
         6       S      H        E
         7       S     M        B', header = TRUE)
```

Los quiero comparar, para ello uso la librería compareDF

```
library(compareDF)

comparar <- compare_df(df1, df2, c("id"))
```

Quiero guardar dos salidas que me da la librería en un excel.
Guardo las salidas en tabla1 y tabla2:

```
tabla1 <- comparar$comparison_table_diff
tabla2 <- create_output_table(comparar)
```

Creo el excel donde guardar cada salida.

```
library(xlsx)

libro <- createWorkbook()

sheet1  <- createSheet(libro, sheetName="HOJA1")
sheet2  <- createSheet(libro, sheetName="HOJA2")

addDataFrame(tabla1, sheet1, startRow=1, startColumn=1,row.names=FALSE)
addDataFrame(tabla2, sheet2, startRow=1, startColumn=1,row.names=FALSE)

saveWorkbook(libro,"PRUEBA.xlsx")
```

La tabla1, que está en la hoja1 ha salido bien.
La tabla2, que está en la hoja dos, ha salido mal (al ser un html)

Me gustaría meter la tabla2 de forma correcta.

Se podría pasar dicha tabla a excel de la siguiente forma:

```
compareDF::create_output_table(comparar, output_type = 'xlsx', file_name = "tabla.xlsx")
```

pero no sé como pasar esto a la pestaña2.

Answer (score 0):

Para guardar yo uso el paquete openxlsx.

Específicamente la función write.xlsx()

La sintaxis, sería la siguiente:

```
write.xlsx(list(tabla1,tabla2), "miruta.xlsx",
 sheetName=c("El nombre de mi tabla1", "El nombre de mi tabla2")
```

Los objetos que quieres guardan deberían de estar en una lista.
Y si deseas con `sheetName` indicas el nombre de las pestañas.

Comment: El problema es q tabla2 está en html y no se guarda bien

Comment: Y cómo esperas que se guarde un archivo en formato html en un excel? Es una tabla lo que está en html?

Comment: Al final conseguí arreglarlo con una libreria para trabajar con excel que me permite añadir nuevas pestañas